# Export Partial Column from Access to Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export the partial or some columns from the below code.

It's exporting everything from Access to Excel.

I appreciated for any suggestion.

```
Dim theFilePath As String
reportname = "X"
theFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\"
theFilePath = theFilePath & reportname & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, reportname, theFilePath, True
MsgBox "The Excel file is Downloaded in your Desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a query which selects the desired columns from your table/query (named `X` in your code) and output the query using the `TransferSpreadsheet` method of the `DoCmd` object.

For example, you might construct a query such as the following, where `YourField1...N` are the desired columns and `x` is your dataset (table/query):

```
select x.YourField1, x.YourField2, x.YourField3 from x
```

Save this query in MS Access as `MyQuery`, then change `reportname = "X"` to `reportname = "MyQuery"`